# How to extract text from element which is part of elements promise in appium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I call this:

```
const wd = require('wd')
const driver = await wd.promiseChainRemote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub")
elements = await driver.elementsByAccessibilityId("commonElementsId")
```

and I received a promise object. My question is, how do I get a single element to which I can apply text() method, so I get the text inside?
I found a solution but it's for java. It looks like this:

```
elements.get(indexOfElement).getText()
```

This obviously doesn't work in javascript. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the text of all the items in a list, you nned to loop over it

```
elements = await driver.elementsByAccessibilityId("commonElementsId")
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].text())
}
```

Comment: I tried getText() but it does't work, I had to use text:
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/text/

Comment: but yeah, I made mistake up there in Java it's getText()

Comment: yes, but only on one element not on multiple elements

Comment: thank you for answer, but the variable elements is not an array it is promise object, you can't call it like the array.

Comment: @andz It returns a list, you can even see an example [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/4ccc8665f8b9edf3f5818dd986e10a6ba58ab1e3/sample-code/javascript-wd/test/basic/ios-selectors.test.js) line 52.

Comment: you were right, I was typing it, in console, without await so i received promise instead of array, so I had to do additional commands
`let el = null` `elements.then((array) => {el = array})` `el.[0].text()`
thanks for help!